# javascript onerror function doesn't execute in the normal sequential flow?

Tags: javascript, opera, onerror

my code is something like this:

```
function func1()  {

     document.getElementById("img").src="pic.jpg";
     ---stament2---;
}

document.getElementById("img").onerror="func2()";
```

In other browser, if there is no pic.jpg, `func2()` is executed and AFTER that, `stament2` is executed; in opera if there is an error loading the image, `func2()` is executed after stament2.

Why did they did it like this? Is there any advantage? IS THERE A WAY to make it run the function called by onerror right when it's called and not after other statements?

if someone could please help....

Does jquery or other library have a crossbrowser solution for onerror applied to images?
hmmm...must learn some jquery

thanks

Comment: What does statement2 do?

Comment: Trying to load an image will complete (or fail) at some point in the future. Relying on *when* that is is a flawed design. The implementation details of a specific case are just leaking through here. See Detect's answer (and accept it already).

Comment: Events can only generally be relied upon to be raised asynchronously (and should only be used with this usage pattern). In certain cases they may be raised synchronously, but this is best described as a "browser quirk". In one case you describe (executed between the assignment and "statement2"), the event is acting synchronously. The only reliable way to handle this is to react asynchronously (handle the onload AND onerror events and continue flow as appropriate from them). This is discussed in Detect's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put statement2 into a separate function and call it at the end of the onLoad of images as well as the end of the onError. Check out: [Having troubles preloading images with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922309/having-troubles-preloading-images-with-javascript)

Comment: worked great...i'm a beginner but i think it's an elegant solution...thanks again